# Implementing a simple floating navigation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, css

I am trying to implement a simple floating navigation using the DOM and Javascript. The following script is triggered using the onscroll event, but nothing happens and debugging through firebug has not been all that enlightening.

```
function float_nav() {
  nav = document.getElementById("nav_container");
  offset = window.pageYOffset + 'px;';
  nav.style.top=offset;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have to add the `;` at the end of `px`. Otherwise I see nothing wrong.

Additional: why don't you use jQuery or something similar?

Comment: I'm a tard, taking out the ';' did it. I just wanted something as lightweight as possible.

Comment: jQuery, imo, isn't a good replacement for something so simple...  Remember that there's always "plain" JavaScript with DOM manipulation.  Adding jQuery would add quite a few kB to the end file, compared to the few hundred bytes required to simply make an element position:fixed, left:0px, top:0px

Answer (score 1):

You can just set up it in styles without javascript

```
#nav_container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  /* IE6 fix for position: fixed */
  _position: absolute;
  _top: expression( document.body.scrollTop + 'px' );
}
```

Comment: I say let ie6 fail and clean up your css.

Comment: I'm using a grid that I prefer to keep intact to keep my css clean, so I vied to use JS